# Efficiently Handling Multiple Optional Constraints in Where Clause

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

This is somewhat of a sequel to [Slow Exists Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094856/slow-exists-check-when-adding-a-conditional-test/1094995).  Alex's suggestion works and successfully avoids code repetition, but I still end up with a second issue.  Consider the example below (From AlexKuznetsov).  In it, I have two branches to handle 1 contraint.  If I had 2 optional constraints, I would end up with 4 branches.  Basically, the number of branches increases exponentially with the number of constraints.

On the other hand, if I use a Multi-Statement Table-valued function or otherwise use temporary tables, the SQL query optimizer is not able to assist me, so things become slow.  I am somewhat distrustful of dynamic SQL (and I've heard it is slow, too).

Can anyone offer suggestions on how to add more constraints without adding lots of if statements?

**Note:** I have previously tried just chaining `x is null or inpo = @inpo` together, but this is very slow.  Keep in mind that while the `inpo = @inpo` test can be handled via some sort of indexing black magic, the nullity test ends up being evaluated for every row in the table.

```
IF @inpo IS NULL BEGIN
  SELECT a,b,c 
    FROM dbo.ReuseMyQuery(@i1)
    ORDER BY c;
END ELSE BEGIN
  SELECT a,b,c 
    FROM dbo.ReuseMyQuery(@i1)
    WHERE inpo = @inpo
    ORDER BY c;
END
```

Variation Two: 2 constraints:

```
IF @inpo IS NULL BEGIN      
    IF @inpo2 IS NULL BEGIN
        SELECT a,b,c 
        FROM dbo.ReuseMyQuery(@i1)
        ORDER BY c;
    END ELSE BEGIN
        SELECT a,b,c 
        FROM dbo.ReuseMyQuery(@i1)
        WHERE inpo2 = @inpo2
        ORDER BY c;
    END
END ELSE BEGIN
    IF @inpo2 IS NULL BEGIN
        SELECT a,b,c 
        FROM dbo.ReuseMyQuery(@i1)
        WHERE inpo = @inpo
        ORDER BY c;
    END ELSE BEGIN
        SELECT a,b,c 
        FROM dbo.ReuseMyQuery(@i1)
        WHERE inpo = @inpo AND
              inpo2 = @inpo2
        ORDER BY c;
    END
END
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is the best reference: http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html

Answer (score 1):

In such cases I use `sp_executesql` as described in Erland's article: [Using sp_executesql](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html#sp_executesql)
Whenever dynamic SQL is used, missing permissions may be a problem, so I have a real network account for unit testing, I add that account to the actual role, and I impersonate with that real account whenever I test dynamic SQL, as described here: [Database Unit Testing: Impersonation](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2008/06/18/database-unit-testing-impersonation.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, that is what I ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select blah from foo    
Where (@inpo1 is null or @inpo1 = inpo1)
and (@inpo2 is null or @inpo2 = inpo2)
```

Apparently this is too slow. Interesting.

Have you considered code generation? Lengthy queries with lots of duplication is only an issue if it has to be maintained directly.

Comment: As I mentioned in Slow Exists check, that solution is slow.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough example. Modify the LIKE statements in the WHERE clause depending if you  want "starts with" or "contains" or an exact match in your query.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.test
@name       AS VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
@address1       AS VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
@address2       AS VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
@city       AS VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
@state      AS VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
@zip_code       AS VARCHAR(50) = NULL
AS

BEGIN

SELECT  [name],
            address1,
            address2,
            city,
            state,
            zip_code
FROM    my_table
WHERE   ([name] LIKE @name + '%' OR @name IS NULL)
            AND (address1 LIKE @address1 + '%' OR @address1 IS NULL)
            AND (address2 LIKE @address2 + '%' OR @address2 IS NULL)
            AND (city LIKE @city + '%' OR @city IS NULL)
            AND (state LIKE @state + '%' OR @state IS NULL)
            AND (zip_code LIKE @zip_code + '%' OR @zip_code IS NULL)
ORDER BY    [name]
END
GO
```

Comment: I tried this previously (mentioned in the initial question).  It is slow.

Answer (score 0):

I realise your question may be purely academic, but if you have real world use cases have you considered only providing optimised queries for the most common scenarios?

Comment: I thought about that as a solution, but consider it something to use if I have no choice rather than an ideal.